# Redirect print() to file in python 2.4

Tags: python

I'm backporting a modern python script to 2.4 to make it compatible with stock RHEL 5.X.  While most of the work has been fairly straight-forward, I can't figure out how to handle this case where I am appending to a file:

```
print("Foo",file=file("/tmp/bar",'ab'))
```

This is a very common construct in the code I'm porting.  I am using the print function from **future**, which works fine, but here it chokes on the "file=file("filename", 'ab')" part.  Apparently this kind of redirection is not supported in 2.4.  Likewise, I haven't found a way for the print function to support the >> operator from the old print.  It would be an enormous task to re-write this script without the print function, so I'd like a solution based on the print function.

I've found plenty of docs showing how to use >> in the old print, or file=file() in the new print function, but nothing that actually works in 2.4.

What is the equivalent Python 2.4 compatible code for this?

Comment: Do you not have the option of installing Python 3, say bundling it all with an installer script, or as an RPM with a Python3 dependency?

Comment: Side-notes: `file` is a deprecated name, gone in Py3. You probably want to use `open`. Additionally, reopening the file each `print` is going to be slow; ideally you open it once and reuse the handle. Of course, depending on use, repeated accumulating writes is often best done with the `logging` module, which avoids the compatibility problems of `print` entirely; I rarely see a `print` (statement or function) in production code, because text logging is done through the `logging` module, and general file I/O is done with the methods on file-like objects directly without `print` overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is pretty awful:

```
print >> file('/tmp/bar', 'ab'), 'Foo'
```

Though of course you should rather write:

```
f = open('/tmp/bar', 'ab')
try:
    print >> f, 'Foo'
finally:
    f.close()
```

to make sure that the output is actually closed and flushed. (Python 2.4 doesn't have `with` statement!).

---

As an alternative to converting everything to `print` statement, you could also try the [`print_`](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/src/ca4580a5a648fc75abc568907e81abc80b05d58c/six.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#six.py-738) function from the [Six: Python 2 and 3 Compatibility Library](https://pythonhosted.org/six/). I am not sure whether the whole library supports 2.4 any longer, but that one function should be OK in 2.4.

Comment: I ended up using the Six compatibility library, as suggested.  Thanks!